# Android, wifi wake up

Tags: android, widget, wifi

When tablet is connected by the wire (charger/usb) the wifi doesn't sleep, when the device is unpluged, the wifi goes sleep and when I ulock the screen, the Icon of  the Wifi is blue but I don't have internet connection, sometimes the icon is grey and I dont have internet too.

I have programmed, if there is no connection and connection to the server timed out I get error, these features  work when the icon is gray, but if the icon is blue, the widget hangs on, and it again works when I turn off wifi, what is wrong?
I think if there is blue icon it thinks that I have connection to the internet, but I have next check if server respond (3 sec) and it should works. But it thniks and thinks until turn off wifi.

On the phone I have 2.2 and I dont have any troubles, on the tablet I've 4.0.3

```
wifi = conn.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);      
mobile = conn.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        if (wifi.isConnected() || mobile.isConnected()) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(uri);
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                urlc.connect();
                if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) { 
                    return true;
                } else { 
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {

                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.0 uses a more aggressive energy conservation methods which may be biting you.
I'd just re-enable wifi... connection setup takes between 3 and 5 seconds in obtaining a new DHCP lease. ITs faster if it already knows who you are (ie IP). Could be a combination of 
both Android hibernating and your AP set to release the lease too aggressively (TTL). What tablet and wifi router are you experiencing this on?

```
 WifiManager wifi;
 wifi = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifi.getConnectionInfo();  // extra if you want connection info
 wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);  // turn it on , if its already on no harm.
```